# Spark DataFrame: count distinct values of every column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, distinct-values

The question is pretty much in the title: Is there an efficient way to count the distinct values in every column in a DataFrame?

The [describe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#describe(scala.collection.Seq)) method provides only the count but not the distinct count, and I wonder if there is a a way to get the distinct count for all (or some selected) columns.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Multiple aggregations would be quite expensive to compute. I suggest that you use approximation methods instead. In this case, approxating distinct count:

```scala
val df = Seq((1,3,4),(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(2,3,5)).toDF("col1","col2","col3")

val exprs = df.columns.map((_ -> "approx_count_distinct")).toMap
df.agg(exprs).show()
// +---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
// |approx_count_distinct(col1)|approx_count_distinct(col2)|approx_count_distinct(col3)|
// +---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
// |                          2|                          2|                          3|
// +---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

The `approx_count_distinct` method relies on **HyperLogLog** under the hood.

The **HyperLogLog** algorithm and its variant HyperLogLog++ (implemented in Spark) relies on the following *clever* observation.

If the numbers are spread uniformly across a range, then the count of distinct elements can be approximated from the largest number of leading zeros in the binary representation of the numbers.

For example, if we observe a number whose digits in binary form are of the form `0…(k times)…01…1`, then we can estimate that there are in the order of 2^k elements in the set. This is a very crude estimate but it can be refined to great precision with a sketching algorithm.

A thorough explanation of the mechanics behind this algorithm can be found in the [original paper](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlFuGaMe07.pdf).

**Note:** Starting **Spark 1.6**, when Spark calls `SELECT SOME_AGG(DISTINCT foo)), SOME_AGG(DISTINCT bar)) FROM df`  each clause should trigger separate aggregation for each clause. Whereas this is different than `SELECT SOME_AGG(foo), SOME_AGG(bar) FROM df` where we aggregate once. Thus the performance won't be comparable when using a `count(distinct(_))` and `approxCountDistinct` (or `approx_count_distinct`).

It's one of the *changes of behavior since Spark 1.6* :

> With the improved query planner for queries having distinct aggregations (SPARK-9241), the plan of a query having a single distinct aggregation has been changed to a more robust version. To switch back to the plan generated by Spark 1.5’s planner, please set spark.sql.specializeSingleDistinctAggPlanning to true. [(SPARK-12077)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12077)

Reference : [Approximate Algorithms in Apache Spark: HyperLogLog and Quantiles](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/05/19/approximate-algorithms-in-apache-spark-hyperloglog-and-quantiles.html).

Comment: Just a caveat: Note that for columns where almost every value is unique,  approx_count_distinct might give up to 10% error in the default configuration and might actually take the same time as count_distinct. It might even return a value that is higher than the actual row count.

Comment: That's correct but the bigger your dataset is, the lower that error is.

Comment: how do you do this in PySpark?

Answer (score 77):

In `pySpark` you could do something like this, using `countDistinct()`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, countDistinct

df.agg(*(countDistinct(col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns))
```

Similarly in `Scala` :

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.countDistinct
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

df.select(df.columns.map(c => countDistinct(col(c)).alias(c)): _*)
```

If you want to speed things up at the potential loss of accuracy, you could also use `approxCountDistinct()`.

Comment: can you please explain what's the `*` for here (in your pyspark solution)?

Comment: The star operator in Python can be used to unpack the arguments from the iterator for the function call, also see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Answer (score 22):

if you just want to count for particular column then following could help. Although its late answer. it might help someone. (`pyspark 2.2.0` tested)

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, countDistinct
df.agg(countDistinct(col("colName")).alias("count")).show()
```

Comment: If you want the answer in a variable, rather than displayed to the user, replace the `.show()` with `.collect()[0][0]`

Answer (score 9):

Adding to desaiankitb's answer, this would provide you a more intuitive answer :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count

df.groupBy(colname).count().show()
```

Comment: Great answer for those who wish to display the counts of each unique value occurring within a column of choice.

Comment: To get # of unique values, just `len(df.groupBy(colname).count().show())` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `count(column name)` function of SQL

Alternatively if you are using data analysis and want a rough estimation and not exact count of each and every column you can use approx_count_distinct function
`approx_count_distinct(expr[, relativeSD])`

Answer (score 0):

This is one way **to create dataframe with every column counts :**

```
> df = df.to_pandas_on_spark()
>         collect_df = []
>         for i in df.columns:
>             collect_df.append({"field_name": i , "unique_count": df[i].nunique()})
>         uniquedf = spark.createDataFrame(collect_df)
```

Output would like below. I used this with another dataframe to compare values if columns names are same.Other dataframe was also created way then joined.

```
df_prod_merged = uniquedf1.join(uniquedf2, on='field_name', how="left")
```

This is easy way to do it might be expensive on very huge data like 1  tb to process but still very efficient when used **to_pandas_on_spark()**

[image]