# Finding cardinality of multiple categorical columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a list of categorical columns from a dataframe and I want to find the cardinality of each of the column. Please guide me. 
I am trying this

```
data.select(cat_columns).distinct().count()
```

but somehow this does not work.
Thanks

Comment: data.select(cat_columns).distinct().count()
This gives me unique rows with all those columns.

Comment: I tried 
`cardinality=[]`
`for col in cat_columns2:`
 `cardinality.append(data.select(col).distinct().count())`
But it is very slow. I don't think it is distributed.

Comment: solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888946/spark-dataframe-count-distinct-values-of-every-column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark DataFrame: count distinct values of every column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888946/spark-dataframe-count-distinct-values-of-every-column)

Answer (score 1):

[approx_count_distinct()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct) should do the trick here if you want to iterate over a large dataframe.

Though, take into consideration it has **rsd – maximum estimation error** allowed (default = 0.05). For rsd < 0.01, it is more efficient to use countDistinct()

```
cols_cardinality = df_dataset.select(*[approx_count_distinct(c).alias(c) for c in df_dataset.columns])
```