# Distinct Record Count in Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, count, distinct, record

I'm trying to display a distinct count of a couple different columns in a spark dataframe, and also the record count after grouping the first column.
So if I had col1, col2, and col3, I want to groupBy col1, and then display a distinct count of col2 and also a distinct count of col3. 
Then, I would like to display the record count after that same groupBy of col1. 
And finally, do this all in one agg statement.. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark DataFrame: count distinct values of every column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888946/spark-dataframe-count-distinct-values-of-every-column)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code you are looking for

```
df.groupBy("COL1").agg(countDistinct("COL2"),countDistinct("COL3"),count($"*")).show
```

=======Tested Below============

```
scala>  val lst = List(("a","x","d"),("b","D","s"),("ss","kk","ll"),("a","y","e"),("b","c","y"),("a","x","y"));
lst: List[(String, String, String)] = List((a,x,d), (b,D,s), (ss,kk,ll), (a,y,e), (b,c,y), (a,x,y))

scala> val rdd=sc.makeRDD(lst);
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[7] at makeRDD at <console>:26

scala> val df = rdd.toDF("COL1","COL2","COL3");
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [COL1: string, COL2: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- COL1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- COL2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- COL3: string (nullable = true)


scala> df.groupBy("COL1").agg(countDistinct("COL2"),countDistinct("COL3"),count($"*")).show
+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|COL1|count(DISTINCT COL2)|count(DISTINCT COL3)|count(1)|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|  ss|                   1|                   1|       1|
|   b|                   2|                   2|       2|
|   a|                   2|                   3|       3|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------+


scala>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you explain how the count($"*") does a record count of the first column after it is grouped?

Comment: Also, would there be a reason why the distinct counts would all be 1 when I do the countDistincts?

Comment: Count($”*”) means just count(*) as in other rdbms sql like Oracle, this means count all .. it counts all records within the group

Comment: count($"*") , count("*")  or count("COL1")  all three will yield same result.. basically counting all rows in a group