# pyspark count distinct on each column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm brand new the pyspark (and really python as well). I'm trying to count distinct on each column (not distinct combinations of columns). I want the answer to this SQL statement:

```
sqlStatement = "Select Count(Distinct C1) AS C1, Count(Distinct C2) AS C2, ..., Count(Distinct CN) AS CN From myTable"

distinct_count = spark.sql(sqlStatement).collect()
```

That takes forever (16 hours) on an 8-node cluster (see configuration below). I'm trying to optimize a 100GB dataset with 400 columns. I am not seeing a way of using dataframe sql primitives like:

```
df.agg(countDistinct('C1', 'C2', ..., 'CN'))
```

as that will again give me unique combinations. There must be a way to make this fast.

---

Master node 
Standard (1 master, N workers)
Machine type
n1-highmem-8 (8 vCPU, 52.0 GB memory)
Primary disk size
500 GB
Worker nodes
8
Machine type
n1-highmem-4 (4 vCPU, 26.0 GB memory)
Primary disk size
500 GB
Local SSDs
1

Comment: `approx_count_distinct` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40889920/9613318)? `Count(Distinct x)`  is __really__ bad.

Comment: Thanks. That is a helpful post. I did a lot of googling and for some reason that post did not come up!

Comment: The other thing I'm trying to do is run a describe() to get all the basic stats. That was also slow. It was 2 hours out of my 16. Any help on speeding up describe() would also be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could benefit from using `cache()`, transformations will be recomputed if you perform multiple actions on the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are using the `.collect()` method which returns all elements of the dataset to the driver and this may cause the driver to run out of memory. See [this link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.collect) for explanation.

You can see what is being passed by running `.explain()` on your query:

```
myquery = spark.sql(sqlStatement)
myquery.explain()
```

You could ease the problem by splitting up your query into multiple queries so you do not calculate `distinct()` on every column at once. This will reduce the amount of data passed at a time.